# How to know class A is extend from class B in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have a class A is extend from class B in ExtJs 4.x. Is there have a function judge class A is extend from class B like "if(obj instanceof Class)" in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @sra's suggestion, you can also use **`isXType()`** on a component level: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-isXType

Answer (score 3):

JS has an instanceof operator:

```
Ext.define('A', {
});

Ext.define('B', {
    extend: 'A'
});

Ext.define('C', {
    extend: 'B'
});

Ext.define('D', {
});

console.log(new B() instanceof A);
console.log(new C() instanceof A);
console.log(new D() instanceof A);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend evans answer!**

But there are other ways to do it on component level by using the [getXTypes()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-getXTypes) method which returns the xType chain as string.

You need to lookup if the searched widget (component) is part of the string.

```
var splitted = ref.getXTypes().split('/'),
    len = splitted.length,
    i = 0;

for(;i < len; i++) {
    if(lookupType == splitted[i])
        // do something
}
```

**Edit**

Due to another problem I stumbled over another way that seems to work.

You can use the `self`, `superclass` and `$className` properties to navigate upwards in the class hierarchy.

Here's a example:

```
Ext.getCmp('customform-1746').self.superclass.$className // echo Ext.form.Panel
Ext.getCmp('customform-1746').self.superclass.self.superclass.$className // echo Ext.panel.Panel
```

You can simply build recursive method which checks and return either `true` or `false`. But again, the `instanceof` operator might be much faster here!